# Bitwise AND operator - Is it used to decrement previous bit interval?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am not sure how to phrase the topic for this question because I am new to bit manipulation and really don't understand how it works.

I'm in the process of reverse engineering a game application just to see how it works and wanted to figure out how exactly the '&' operator is being used in a method.

Partial Code:

```
int n = (random numbers will be provided below)
int n2 = n & 1920 // interested in this line of code
switch (n2){
//ignore n2 value assignment inside of cases
    case 256: {
        n2 = 384;
        break;
    case 384: {
        n2 = 512;
        break;
    case 512: {
        n2 = 0
        break;
```

Test Values:

```
Input Values | Output Values | Substituting Values
n = 387      | n2 = 384      | ( 387 & 1920 ) = 384
n = 513      | n2 = 512      | ( 513 & 1920 ) = 512
n = 12546    | n2 = 256      | ( 12546 & 1920 ) = 256
n = 18690    | n2 = 256      | ( 18690 & 1920 ) = 256
```

Based on this use case I have a few questions:

What is the & operator doing in this example?

- To me it looks like most of the values are being rounded down to the nearest bit interval, except for the numbers greater than 10000

What is so important about the number `1920`?

How did they come up with this number to get to a specific bit interval? (if possible to figure out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you need to do, to understand bit manipulation, is to convert all base-10 decimal numbers into a number format showing bits, i.e. base-2 binary numbers or base-16 hexadecimal numbers (if you've learned to read those yet).

Bits are numbered from the right, starting at 0.

```java
Decimal     Hex            Binary
    256 = 0x100 =   0b1_0000_0000
    384 = 0x180 =   0b1_1000_0000
    512 = 0x200 =  0b10_0000_0000
   1920 = 0x780 = 0b111_1000_0000
                    | | |  |    |
                   10 8 7  4    0   Bit Number
```

As you can see, `n & 1920` will clear all but bits 7-10.

As long as `n` doesn't have any set bits above 10, i.e. greater than `0x7FF = 2047`, the effect is as you stated, the values are being rounded down (truncated) to the nearest bit interval, i.e. multiple of 128.

Comment: And in this spirit, don't use decimal literals in source code here. This line should have been written as `n & 0x780`.

Comment: Or `0xF << 7`, which is compiled to the same thing but easier for a human to see that it has four 1 bits starting from position 7.

Comment: @Thilo OP is *"reverse engineering a game application"*, so we're likely looking at disassembled code.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the detailed answer. If I am not mistaken, from your answer above, they seem to be doing some type of flag checking?

Answer (score 0):

```
128 + 256 + 512 + 1024 = 1920.

These are also powers of 2.  let ^ be power of.

128 = 2^7 
256 = 2^8 
512 = 2^9
1024 = 2^10
```

The exponent also represents the location of the bit in the number, going from right to left starting with bit 0.

By ANDing the a value with 1920 you can see if any of the bits are set.

Let's say you wanted to see if n had only bit 7 was set.

```
if ((n & 1920) == 128) {
   // it is set.
}
```

Or to see if it had bits 7 and 8 set.

```
if ((n & 1920) == 384) {
  //  then those bits are set.
}
```

You can also set a particular bit by using `|`.

```
n |= 128.  Set's bit 7 to 1.
```